# How do I loop over an array in a function in C?

Tags: c

I want to generate a `16 byte` long `unsigned char array` and fill it with random chars **except** some.

I am a noob in C still, and I still don't understand when to use pointers and such to correctly use arrays yet.

*What I have right now*:

```c
bool has_illegal_character(uint8_t * arr, int length){
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(length); i++){
        if (*arr == 0x01) return true;
        else if (*arr == 0x04) return true;
        else if (*arr == 0x05) return true;
        else if (*arr == 0x15) return true;
        else if (*arr == 0x00) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

uint8_t arr[16] = {0};
while(has_illegal_character(arr, sizeof(arr))){
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr; i++)
   {
        arr[i] = rand() % 255;
   }
}
```

This does not work.

What is the correct way to create an array filled with random characters except `0x01`, `0x04`, `0x05` and `0x15`, ideally by using a function in C?

Comment: Your `has_illegal_character` function will only ever check the first character in the array. It also does not loop over the length of the array, but over the size of the length variable (int might be 4 bytes in your environment). Also, instead of checking the entire array every time you generate a new random value, check just that random value.

Comment: Remember to define `true` and `false` as 1 and 0, if not done yet.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(length); i++){
                 ^
                 |
                wut
```

Is not correct, you're not interested in looping over the bytes of `length` itself. It should just be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice this mistake.